# MS Graph api user authentication failing

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am starting out with MS Graph API. I need a login example with least amount of user intervention; if possible at most only once and the first time app is run. The sample GraphTutorial app (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-dotnet-core/tree/main/demo) seems to require user intervention every time it is run with a code required to be manually entered.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Calling microsoft graph api need Bearer access token in the request header, this token could be generated by serveral flows. As you said that you'd like to achieve a feature which can avoid user intervention, I think you could use client credential flow to generate the token, but this token can't be used for those apis which requires delegation api permission. Could you pls tell us which api you'd like to call?

Comment: I think using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) will make sense. Each time you wanna call that graph api, you can use this flow to generate an access token, and you don't need to do any other operations such as enter account and password, and you can use that token to call the api. Here's the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph) on it.

Comment: Is there any progress sir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the graph api without login, it's possible with client credential flow. Microsoft also provides [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph) for it. I also tested and pick some of the key code like below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace WebApplication4clientflow.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<string> Index()
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("azure_ad_app_clientid")
                    .WithClientSecret("client_secret_of_your_app")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com"))
                    .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above, we can generate access token to call graph api, but pls note, it's not suitable for those apis that don't [support application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/useranalytics-get-settings?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=http#permissions), like below:

[image]

Pls feel free to let me know if you met further problems.

Comment: If you feel my post is helpful, could you pls accept it as the answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's my pleasure  :D